# Why the difference in neofetch and free (RAM) output?

Tags: linux-mint, ram, free

```
wadewayne@Cheetah:~$ neofetch
MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMmds+.        wadewayne@Cheetah 
MMm----::-://////////////oymNMd+`     ----------------- 
MMd      /++                -sNMd:    OS: Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia x86_64 
MMNso/`  dMM    `.::-. .-::.` .hMN:   Host: Inspiron 15-3567 
ddddMMh  dMM   :hNMNMNhNMNMNh: `NMm   Kernel: 5.4.0-77-generic 
    NMm  dMM  .NMN/-+MMM+-/NMN` dMM   Uptime: 9 mins 
    NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   Packages: 3130 
    NMm  dMM  -MMm  `MMM   dMM. dMM   Shell: bash 4.4.20 
    NMm  dMM  .mmd  `mmm   yMM. dMM   Resolution: 1366x768 
    NMm  dMM`  ..`   ...   ydm. dMM   WM: i3 
    hMM- +MMd/-------...-:sdds  dMM   Theme: Arc-Dark [GTK2/3] 
    -NMm- :hNMNNNmdddddddddy/`  dMM   Icons: Pop [GTK2/3] 
     -dMNs-``-::::-------.``    dMM   Terminal: terminator 
      `/dMNmy+/:-------------:/yMMM   CPU: Intel i3-6006U (4) @ 2.000GHz 
         ./ydNMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM   GPU: Intel HD Graphics 520 
            .MMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMMM      Memory: 367MiB / 3801MiB 

                                                              


wadewayne@Cheetah:~$ free -h
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           3.7G        325M        2.3G         39M        1.1G        3.1G
Swap:          521M          0B        521M
```

[image: Screenshot]

Hi. I don't understand why `neofetch` and `free -h` output different result for RAM usage. Which one's more accurate?

Comment: can you define what "accurate free memory" means to you? (it's really not unambiguous, and what is the relevant measure depends on very much on what you need to do.)

Comment: FYI, https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/blob/master/neofetch#L2660 uses the slightly surprising formula `MemUsed = Memtotal + Shmem - MemFree - Buffers - Cached - SReclaimable`, and I'm super confused for whom that would be useful (not like shared memory was gratis for a system), but there you go.

Answer (score 4):

`neofetch` calculates used memory as

```
MemUsed = Memtotal + Shmem - MemFree - Buffers - Cached - SReclaimable
```

see [neofetch FAQ](https://github.com/dylanaraps/neofetch/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#linux-is-neofetchs-memory-output-correct) for more information.

`free` calculates used memory as

```
used = total - free - buffers - cache
```

so the difference is neofetch considers shared memory (tmpfs) as used (*cache* in `free` is *Cached + SReclaimable* in `neofetch`). See [free manpage](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/free.1.html) for more information about columns in free output.

If you add *used* and *shared* from your `free` output you get 364 MiB so the difference is only 3 MiB, which can be attributed to some small change in RAM usage or rounding.